# AttributeError when using statsmodels on clean anaconda installation

Tags: python, anaconda, statsmodels

I am working with the statsmodels package on a clean installation of Anaconda (downloaded today), on an entirely clean installation of macOS Catalina.

However, upon running

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import pandas as pd

weekly_df = pd.read_csv('Data/Weekly.csv')

form = 'Direction_Up ~ Lag1 + Lag2 + Lag3 + Lag4 + Lag5 + Volume'
model_10b = smf.Logit.from_formula(formula = form, data = weekly_df)
```

I get the error

`module 'statsmodels.formula.api' has no attribute 'Logit'`

It seems to be an installation issue, based on earlier suggestions in similar problems. I tried to fix it reinstalling statsmodels on conda (conda install statsmodels), however that did not solve it. I removed and reinstalled Anaconda, and that did not solve it either.

What could be the problem here? Thanks a lot for helping out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I get the error
>   module `statsmodels.formula.api` has no attribute `Logit`

This is not an install issue. The `formula.api` does not contain uppercase `Logit` anymore. It has been removed to avoid confusion with lower case `logit`

Upper case `Logit` is the name of the class and the data has to be provided in the form of arrays or pandas DataFrames.

Lower case `logit` which is in `formula.api` takes a formula and a DataFrame or dictionary to define the model and data. This is just a convenience alias for the `from_formula` method of the `Logit` class.

Answer (score 0):

Request you to run the below command in Anaconda Prompt to install statsmodels

```
conda install -c anaconda statsmodels
```

It worked for me :)

This import all the modules from statsmodels.

Comment: Nope, didn't work. To add, when I ran your suggestion it told me this: 
The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

  ca-certificates                                 pkgs/main --> anaconda
  certifi                                         pkgs/main --> anaconda
  conda                                           pkgs/main --> anaconda
  statsmodels                                     pkgs/main --> anaconda

Comment: Could you please post an image , so that i can understand better. Because I followed the same  steps and it worked for me in my windows machine